# SharePoint show parent site on breadcrumb

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages, breadcrumbs

I have replaced

```
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
```

with

```
<asp:SiteMapPath
 runat="server"
 SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider"
 RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
 NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode"
 CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode"
 RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode"
 HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
 SkipLinkText=""/>
```

in the v4 master page, however I still do not see parent site on the breadcrumb.
Is it supposed to be done in parent or subsite v4 master page?

Thank you in advance.

Paul.